# Creating relations one table to many tables using a two-field primary key

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I'm not a pro (and don't speak english very well) but I'm trying to create a relation between a table and 5 other tables using a primary key of two fields.

I don't know if it's possible and if it's the right way to do what I want, so every suggestion is appreciated.

This is what I thought:

```
TabA    TabB    TabC    TabD    TabE
Id           Id           Id           Id           Id
.......    .......    .......    .......    ....... (other fields)

EventsTab
TabRif
IdRif
....... (other fields or not?)
```

EventsTab Primary Key = (TabRif, IdRif)

Now, assuming that in TabA there is an Id = 3, in EventsTab the primary key will be "A3".
How can I link this value as foreign key? Is it possible? Is the right way?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you saying you want EventsTab to have a foreign key that references TabA, or TabA to have a foreign key that references EventsTab? Do you really need it to be an enforced Foreign Key, or can you handle the data integrity yourself and then just use the appropriate joins when you need to combine two tables?

Comment: It's really a bad idea to have to refer to specific fields or tables within your data in order to make a join to that specific field or table. Instead of making a seperate table for TabA, TabB, TabC, TabD, and TabE perhaps they should all be in one table with an extra field that tells you whether they are "A, B, C, D, E". Then you are Joining on fields instead of trying to join on database objects.

Comment: As I said, I'm not a pro, so I'm worried about the data integrity but I don't know what I really need to preserve it. I also thought to store data in another table using EventsTab only as link to the 5 tables. Please show me a way ...

Comment: I can't unify the five tables for many reasons (too complex to explain here). I need to notify about the data in the 5 tables and take note about notification (into the 6th table that I want to link). Another way could be creating 5 different tables for notifications but don't seems to be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

When you say "in EventsTab the primary key will be A3" do you mean this is actually TabRif = A and IdRif = 3? So the primary key is actually {A,3} and not just a string "A3"? In which case this is better, but then in each of your other tables I would add a column, something like 'TabName', and have 2 foreign keys.

```
TabA (TabName foreign key -> EventsTab.TabRif, Id foreign key -> EventsTab.TabId)
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: So the primary key is actually {A,3} and not just a string "A3"? the answer is YES. Then I'll need to change the primary key for the five tables using also the 'TabName' column?

Comment: Do you have a foreign key in TabA, TabB etc that references EventsTab, or a foreign key in EventsTab that references TabA, TabB etc? Because you cannot do the second one (well you could with some serious hacking but it would be baaaaaaad)

Comment: EventsTab depends from TabA, TabB, .... records: EventsTab stores the notified events and I need it to know what it's been notified (from the five tables)

Comment: In that case you do not want foreign keys (or not in the strictest sense of a foreign key constraint). You will have to ensure data integrity yourself - whenever you insert a row into EventsTab, first check that the Id exists in the Tab table that you are referencing. Then, when you come to query, you can do joins as normal, something like: select * from EventsTab e inner join TabA ta on e.IdRif = ta.Id and e.TabRif = 'A'